# DoWork of backgroundworker skipped on another computer

Tags: .net, vb.net

in a project I'm using a Backgroundworker (in vb.net).
I work under Windows 8 Pro (64bit) and the project work fine on it... BUT if I transfer the executable on a machine with Windows 7 (64bit) happen a strange thing! The DoWork of Backgroundworker doesn't work, it skip directly to RunWorkerCompleted.
I don't understand why.
I compile it with Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition.
Have you got ideas to solve this?
Thank you.

This is some code:

```
Private Sub bgw_extract_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw_extract.DoWork
        MsgBox("test dowork") 'this appear
        extract_cycle() 'this isn't executed
        MsgBox("end dowork") 'this isn't executed
End Sub


Private Sub extract_cycle()
'nothing is executed here
        MsgBox("test2") 'not executed
        Try
            'my code....
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Extract Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
End Sub


Private Sub bgw_extract_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles
 bgw_extract.RunWorkerCompleted
         MsgBox("RunWorkCompleted") 'this is executed in every case
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the problem with a minimal example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unhandled exception not caught in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463408/unhandled-exception-not-caught-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you show some code, it's kind of difficult to guess what you are doing?

Comment: With a minimal example works (if I put three MsgBox only in DoWork it.. works). Only with extract_cycle() the DoWork run only for the first row that it contain and then skip to RunWorkerCompleted.
It's all executed only in my Windows 8 pc.

Comment: What I normally do is, avoid using the UI related actions inside `DoWork()` event. For example, calling `MessageBox.Show()` or updating a control. So, I won't call any functions that refers it too. I only update the UI thread in the `ProgressChanged()` event as well as the `RunWorkerCompleted()` event. Not sure if that helps. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your extract_cycle method references an assembly that is not present on the target machine; and an exception is therefore thrown when it is JITted (and therefore before `MsgBox("test2")` is executed).

If you [catch unhandled exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) (or even look in the Event Log) you should be able to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! With a Try Catch ex As Exception I found that it's "could not load file or assembly 'Ionic.Zip'" that is a .dll, how can I include it?

Comment: @Kaos, you can copy it to the same directory as your other assemblies, or possibly run an installer that will install it in the GAC.